# After drive format unable to use drive

Tags: ubuntu, gparted

I am using Elementary OS and I am having an issue with formatting a drive and getting access denied when trying to move data to it.

I use gparted to format an internal 1tb drive to ext4 and it shows the drive with correct file system when I refresh gparted. After this, I mount the drive but received an access denied when trying to move any data to it.

There is a lost+found directory in it using 2% (about 14 GB) of my drive and it shows up every time after I format the drive. When trying to browse after mounting the drive I get the error: This does not belong to you.

After unmounting the drive, I can see it in Nautilus but am I unable to see in gparted. When trying to mount the drive again sometimes it works and other times I get the error: Unable to unmount 1.0 TB Filesystem. Daemon is inhibited.

I have rebooted my computer and the drive shows back up in gparted but formatting gives me the same issue with access denied and lost+found folder. All other drives work without issue.

Comment: Do not worry about `lost+found` dir, it is a legacy from old time. Which command do you use to mount it ? and when mounted, can you give us the result of  `df` and `mount` command ?

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a basic permission issue to me.

As root, run **chmod +777 /path/to/mountpoint** (like /mnt/drive) to allow all users unrestricted access to the mounted drive.